# Do inner-routed cables have segments without a housing?

Tags: frames, cable-routing

Bowden cables (whether for shifting or for brakes) running outside a
frame save a little weight and expense by using the frame for
compression in lieu of the housing in long stretches along the
frame—using ferrules and cable stops brazed/soldered onto the frame.

Do inner-routed cables also sometimes have segments without a housing? This would significantly complicate replacing a cable, and the movement of the inner cable will eventually cause damage, by fraying the cable and by slowly cutting through something else, if it touches anything inside.

Background: a cross-section reveals a lot about the inner working of a device. A shoe shown sliced will tell me, as with a bike, how much mileage I can expect to get out of it. But since no one has yet sliced a bike frame to show us the details of inner-routed cables, I need to ask.

Comment: Have I got the sub-reddit for you!   https://www.reddit.com/r/ThingsCutInHalfPorn/comments/49tvon/carbon_fiber_bicycle_frame_xpost_bicycling_2048/

Comment: "little cups (name?)" - "cable stops".

Comment: @Criggie Fascinating! And all for the edification of the reddit public.

Comment: @davmac for minor corrections like that, you're totally able to hit [edit] and make the change yourself.  OP can always roll back edits that don't help.  The only time I'd stop to  clarify an edit like that is if I don't know what was originally intended.

Comment: Running shifting cables without housing and using the frame for compression also improves shifting performance, as the frame is stiffer than the housing and therefore less cable pull is lost to the housing compressing itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mine does.

It's a Canondale Topstone, and the outers for the derailleurs stop where the cables enter the top of the downtube. They come out bare under the bottom bracket.

At least one model of Synapse routes the rear derailleur cable further inside (along the chainstay as well), in a light and flexible sleeve that serves mainly to guide a new cable into place, as it can't resist compression.  Here the cable turns under the BB, guided under the BB shell. I've worked on this and it wasn't easy.

I've also had full length outers that went inside the downtube (a GT from 2010).

Don't forget that gear cables are always under tension once installed. There's a fairly tight limit on how much they can flex. And they're guided as necessary, by end stops for example. On my Topstone, the exit point under the bottom bracket is a plastic guide that ensures the cables run away from the tube walls.

Comment: Just to be clear: when a maker (Canondale) eliminates the housing inside the frame, they _completely_ eliminate the housing. Hence the two points of entry & exit must be within sight of each other. The "thin and flexible sleeve" must itself not carry compression, and then the housing must go inside it, or else it does carry compression, in which case it effectively becomes the housing.

Comment: On mine, they're in sight of each other, but don't rule out a well-defined intermediate turning point.  The Synapse uses that because the entry is at the top of the downtube, and the RD exit is at the back of the chainstay.  The cable passes under the BB, around the BB shell, in its sleeve.  But just poking a new cable down the sleeve after pulling out the old one is far from easy

Comment: I guess the question is whether one might sometimes need an "endoscope" to see where the cable is being driven. If there is a turning point, it seems you'd need more than just a prayer to know that the cable is resting where you expect it.

Comment: An endoscope might help, but it would need to be thinner than most engineering ones.  The Synapse has and access port under the BB, a rubber/plastic cover that can be removed for access. The exit guide on the Topstone looks like it might also give a bit of access.  This make it possible; it doesn't make it easy.  But in other fields, you don't need to see where something is going to route it - you can feel, hear, pull with a magnet (we considered that on  my friends' Synapse but my spare RD cables were non-magnetic stainless) or even blow/suck a pilot line

Answer (score 1):

It happens on occasion. My old 2019 Trek X-Caliber hardtail had this type of setup. Cables entered the top of the downtube and exited at the bottom. There were cable stops welded to the inside of the frame. There was no risk of frame damage because the downtube is straight.

It was indeed extremely difficult to route the cables because you needed to get the cable through the little holes in the cable stops, but it was all inside the frame and the only access/line of sight you had was the 5mm hole in the frame. Felt like I was like performing laparoscopic surgery, but without the camera.

Perhaps unsurprisingly, Trek moved to plain holes and full housing for the 2020 model frame (which I came to own after the 2019 cracked under warranty). I suppose the reduction in cable housing used per bike and the slight decrease in friction were not worth the hassle.

Comment: Neat.. but now it seems that there is another advantage to getting rid of the housing inside the frame. If an inner cable runs taut (as it must be) inside the frame, then the risk of cable slap and rattling noises can more easily be controlled. Are we still in the early stages of inner routing, and the right solutions are not yet well understood? Someone on chat recently suggested that rattling of inner cables is a factor being used to distinguish between different market segments, justified by the cost of properly insulating cables. A bare inner cable could solve rattling, and cheaply.

Comment: @Sam There’s definitely no rattling with the housing-free design, but in my opinion housing rattle is a rudimentary engineering oversight. It is really not difficult to restrain a cable running through a tube…all it takes is a bit of foam liner or a few zip ties and access holes. Regarding cost, it cannot be cheap welding cable stops to the inside of frame tubes and then paying assembly workers to deal with that mess.

Comment: With groupsets amateur mechanics are used to reading the Dealer's Manual to find out how to maintain the components. Does something similar need to be done with frames? Before buying a frame, the (enthusiast) buyer would read the _frame's_ Dealer Manual and would decide whether the solutions used for internal routing are up to the buyer's expectations.

Comment: @Sam They are already often available in the form of assembly and service documentation. It’s just certain brands that don’t make such info easily available to the public. And, for the careful buyer, the details of the cable routing setup are indeed very important and can make or break the purchase. For example, if a (carbon) frame has molded cable routing tubes, you cannot run a reversed brake setup with left hand rear, right hand front.

Answer (score 1):

It pretty much depends on the segment. To take two examples:

- On an entry-level suspended hybrid: no housing inside the frame. Cables are only running in the downtube. They enter from the side of the downtube, and there's an opening in the downtube at the level of the bottom bracket where they exit from, From the bottom bracket, there's no housing and cables are mounted under the chainstays.
- On an upper-level e-hardtail, equipped for "utility" use, with fenders, rack, lights: full housing, but the cables are entering in the stem and totally internally routed. Rear brake and derailleur cables (and the speed sensor one) exit from the chainstays.

On your comment that "Someone on chat recently suggested that rattling of inner cables is a factor being used to distinguish between different market segments": the problem is not so much for derailleur cables (and brake cables for non-hydraulic setups), that remain under tension, but for hydraulic hoses that have no tension - on the example of the hybrid given above, I had to use zip ties to "fasten" the hose inside the downtube.

I don't think the right solutions are not well understood, they are understood, and depending on the segment, a solution is chosen or not. For example of the hybrid above, they probably expect the bikes to be used dominantly on pavement, where rattling problems are less of an issue. In the upper-segment example, the bike is advertised as all-rounder, more care is given because it's an expectation of the client - and also because cables are almost entirely internally routed, the path taken by the cables is much more complex.

Comment: A buyer, of any product, can expect to have a functioning device, right out of the shop. If I buy a ten-speed countertop mixer and on the first day of use I find that something rattles on speeds 6 & 7, but that it otherwise works perfectly, I would return it and ask for my money back. The trouble is that a buyer who expects cables not to rattle in a bike will in general be unable to return the bike and get their money back, because the rattling may manifest only in specific speeds and in quieter environments than those around the shop.

Comment: It is the buyer's prerogative to insist on a silent frame. Whether they choose to pay for the up-market segment or to go to a competitor or skip the purchase altogether is a different issue. Of course a shop also does not want people to "buy" a bike, go on a joy ride, then return a now-used product. It would seem that the only solution is to buy only after one has thoroughly test driven a bicycle. I just can't think of any other product where the QA is the responsibility of the buyer.

Comment: @Sam I don't disagree with you, nor defend the attitude of manufacturers. I just describe it. Market segmentation is seen in every industry, and as usual, what truly differentiates upper-segments and lower-segments is usually not visible in the spec sheets. Note that some consider that silent frame is a part of a functional bike, and are proposing external routing for the rear break hydro hose. But the brand of my hybrid has decided that having something that look nice in a showroom was apparently more important than a silent frame.